# error C2061 while passing vector as an argument

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error:

```
1>b:\projects\c++\wolvesisland\wolvesisland\wolvesisland\board.h(22): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vector'
```

while trying to pass vector as an argument.

(it's about function move())

Code:

Board.h

```
    #pragma once

    #include <vector>



    enum field_state {is_wolfm, is_wolff, is_rabbit, is_bush, is_nobody};
    struct state{
        field_state field;
        int number;
    };

    class Board
    {
    private:
        state island[20][20];


    public:
        Board(void);
        ~Board(void);
        void fill(int,int,int,int, vector<LivingForm*>*);
        state get_island(int,int);
        void set_state(int,int,field_state,int);
    };
```

and the function declaration in Board.cpp:

```
    void Board::fill(int rabbit,int wolfm,int wolff,int bush,vector <LivingForm*> *creatures)
```

Comment: You should probably pass that vector by reference and make it contain smart pointers.

Answer (score 2):

`vector` lives in the `std` namespace, so you need to refer to ut as `std::vector`:

```
void fill(int,int,int,int, std::vector<LivingForm*>*);
//                         ^^^
```